# Why Does the T1000 Have to Function as a Single Large Unit?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

In *Terminator 2* we see the T1000 get broken up or frozen and shattered.  It's clear that when it's broken into smaller pieces, those pieces have enough intelligence to seek other (apparently preferably larger) pieces and rejoin.  We only see the T1000 operate as a single, full-sized functioning unit.

But it never functions as a smaller unit.  For instance, when the T800, Sarah, and John are in the police car and the T1000 is hanging on with grappling hook hands, the T800 shoots the T1000 in the arm, breaking the arm so the T1000 falls off.  A single hook is left lodged in the police car.  This hook could have liquefied, and dropped into the trunk, and from there, as a small unit, done anything it needed to, almost unobserved, to get close to John Conner and kill him.

There would be many times a smaller, hidden version of the T1000 could have reached John unobserved and killed him in a number of different ways.

Is it ever made clear that a T1000 has to function as one large unit or can't split into smaller units that do more than just reunite?

Comment: /Imagines a lego-figurine-sized T1000 crawling around the trunk of a car

Comment: The original Terminator was a T800, not T100. (I'm not able to submit that change as an edit, sorry.)

Comment: or at least the liquified hook inside the police car should transmit radio signals with location of car

Comment: Commenting rather than answering because I have no idea of the canonicity of this, but I always just assumed there was one of those Cyberdyne chips floating around somewhere inside the T-1000, and that parts of it that were separated from the chip had little if any ability to act autonomously. The hook doesn't move or change shape until the T-1000 gets near it, so I assumed it was being controlled remotely by the chip.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The processing power required to decide "let's merge all droplets together" is somewhat different from "complete the mission of killing John Connor". Since T1000 is supposed to be a [Nanomorph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanomorph), the processing power is proportional to amount of material in a body.

From T1000 Wiki:

> The Special Edition DVD release contains additional scenes in the steel foundry showing that the effects of being frozen and shattered caused the T-1000 to glitch, causing its extremities to morph and match into its surroundings against the T-1000's will (such as its hand latching on and taking on the metallic texture and caution striping of a guardrail). In the Special Edition, this glitch is what enabled John Connor to see through its ruse when it impersonated his mother.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought that it was the heat of the foundry that caused the T-1000's feet to meld with the floor.

Answer (score 16):

> The smaller the volume of particles, the less intelligent each piece became. Combined, the T-1000 was incredibly capable; however, when in pieces, it merely tried to get back to the whole again.
>   - [terminator.wikia Series 1000 article](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Series_1000#Self-recovering)

This quote is unreferenced, but according to this, if it split itself it would be too dumb to pose any threat.

Comment: This makes the most sense IMO. A group intelligence where the whole becomes greater than the sum of the parts. It was just amazing coincidence that the mass necessary to become smart enough to hunt John Conner was roughly the size of Robert Patrick.

Comment: @Xantec: I'd assume the necessary size/mass was "at most" as big as Robert Patrick, and that the machines could decide to send a bit more to match his size (or a size of typical human) to make it easier for him to blend into environment.

Comment: @liori I'd assume the necessary size/mass was **"A bit more"** big as Robert Patrick, the machine decided to send a bit **less** to match his size, but fail because of this decision!

Answer (score 11):

It is made clear in the function of the unit that the T-1000 is a single composite technology that is unable to create autonomous functional units. It can mimic clothing, helmets, glasses and other props, but they do not function unless they have no moving parts. The gun on the policeman's uniform is just a visual aid, however the baton is not. The primary goal of the T-1000 was mimicry, infiltration and concealment. It didn't need to be able to become smaller versions of itself to be effective.

Likely this is a form of nanotechnology that takes its instruction set from a primary computer within the center of the device. Though the claim is the device was comprised of individual nanocomputers whose sum was greater than the parts, that would make the device far more vulnerable to attack. There would always need to be a place with the primary instruction set was kept to ensure all of the parts could perform higher functions. In modern computers, this would be the Central Processing Unit. Each individual element of the device could not store all of the instructions required for function, but could have a simple set of hardwired protocols in the event of being broken off (find other units, recombine, restart core processes, activate primary OS, review main objectives).

Since its operating system functions in a similar way to the earlier models we have to assume what is changed is how the device operates with it's fluid form being the primary advancement. Even though it was durable it could be stunned or slowed by sufficient traumatic shock.

It must take a great amount of operating capacity to function even as a single unit, since it is limited to making solid shapes such as swords or ice-picks. It cannot even create simple ranged weapons of itself such as guns, bows or even pneumatic flechette launchers.

Guns make sense since bullets would require chemical interactions to propel bullets. Bows or crossbow like mechanisms make less sense, unless the device cannot create tension regions similar to a bow. A pneumatic system makes less sense since compression of air can be a simple mechanical process and the flechettes would require no chemical propellant.

While the device was brilliantly sophisticated, it lacked ingenuity and was more of a blunt instrument in its application of its killing technique. The device could have created heavy darts or other missile weapons (javelins) that are very effective at killing humans, particularly with its superhuman strength and computer-assisted targeting.

Comment: The T-1000 doesn't use a primary computer or any form of hardware like previous models. It is composed solely of the liquid metal, which is infused with billions of nanites which operated like a collective processing unit. Also, I think you only meant "the gun on the policeman's uniform" as an example, but keep in mind the pistol he carried throughout the film was an actual handgun recovered from the police officer he killed in the beginning (same place he got the car & the idea for the uniform).

Comment: @Thaddeus: The franchise has been rebooted as you will see with Genesys and that is EXACTLY what the Asian T-1000 does. He is able to break off his arms and use them as javelins.

Answer (score 3):

The novel explains that when the T-1000 was shattered or divided somehow the fragments only had the overriding purpose to seek one another (to a limited amount of miles of distance(which am not geek enough to remember :/  ))

Answer (score 2):

If the T-1000 splits, which piece is in charge? I would imagine it functions as a single larger unit for many reasons, not the least of which because every part of it is designed to *be* or *join with* the main mass. The main mass is ultimately in control. If it did not work this way, well. An excerpt from John Carpenter's *The Thing.*

> MacReady: We're gonna draw a little bit of everybody's blood... 'cause we're gonna find out who's The Thing. Watchin' Norris in there gave me the idea that... maybe every part of him was a whole, every little piece was an individual animal with a built-in desire to protect its own life. Ya see, when a man bleeds, it's just tissue, but blood from one of you Things won't obey when it's attacked. It'll try and survive... crawl away from a hot needle, say.

A Terminator is a machine with a purpose: it has to survive, not for survival's sake, but to complete an assignment. It could not afford this kind of dissension on a cellular level.